# Asp.Net Core 2.1 Windows Auth. HttpContext.User.Identity.Name not working in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

Environment:

Windows 10
IIS 10 / Visual Studio 2017 Community w/ IIS Express
Windows Authentication security feature installed
Windows Authentication Enabled & Basic Authentication Enabled & Anonymous Authentication Disabled

I have a Asp.Net Core 2.1 Project and this project will work in intranet. So i need to windows authentication.

STARTUP:

```
 public class Startup
    {
        private IConfigurationRoot _appSettings;
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
            _appSettings = new ConfigurationBuilder()
             .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
             .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
             .Build();

        }

        private IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {


            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
            services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

            services.AddSession(options => {
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(8640); //Sessions Time
            });
            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

            services.AddDbContext<PMContext>();
            services.AddSingleton<IConfigurationRoot>(_appSettings);
            PMContext.ConnectionString = _appSettings.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
            services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHangfireServer();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseSession();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseStatusCodePages();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();
            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Intro}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

        }
    }
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.Run(async (context) =>
    {
        await context.Response.WriteAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
        {                
            UserName = context?.User?.Identity?.Name
        }));
    });
```

//In my home controller;

**var UserComputerName = contextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;**

This code working my localhost but don't working in IIS Server :/ I tried same error solves but I couldn't solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have disabled anonymous authentication in IIS.
Next  you will get the user details in the controller if  you call User.Identity.Name , you don't need to  inject HttpContextAccessor if your using windows auth.