# ASP.Net Core 2.2 MVC Windows authentication and windows username issue on IIS

Tags: .net-core, windows-authentication

I am working on ASP.Net core 2.2 MVC application. Using windows authentication to authenticate the user and i want to display the logged in user in my home page after successful login.

How ever am using following functions/methods to get the username which is working fine at debugging mode as expected.

But when i hosted in IIS i am not getting the username instead am getting

ApplicationPoolname, Machinename

```
       ViewBag.username = Environment.UserName;
        ViewBag.username = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERNAME");
        ViewBag.username = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
        ViewBag.username = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).ToString();
```

the below code is with bad request 500
IHttpContextAccessor

When i use

ViewBag.username = this.User.Identity.Name;

i am getting environment variable error with sensitive information is passing as its passing the username.

So nothing is working so far and any solution for this am dig more over all the documentation from MS and as well as the forums and no solution yet.

already checked following threads

[Asp.Net Core 2.1 Windows Auth. HttpContext.User.Identity.Name not working in IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51821277/asp-net-core-2-1-windows-auth-httpcontext-user-identity-name-not-working-in-iis)

Appreciate if any one could give me the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

"environment variable error with sensitive information is passing as its passing the username." is common error as it doesn't display exact error in production environment. 
disable anonymous authentication.